# 2.82 signed with unknown CA?

Tags: installation

Why is the new 2.82 signed with a cert that is not recognized by Windows? Is this typical?

I don't typically install exes with invalid or unrecognized certs.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Thanks, folks. Electric_Wizard, Mine is signed with the same CA, the Root CA is Certum. Just wasn't recognized by SmartScreen (yet). I wasn't aware this was available on the MS store. I'll just go ahead with the install. Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry, everything is fine.

**Main Reason**
Since Blender 2.8, the installer is signed by the Blender foundation for improved security. However:

> *Ray Molenkamp (Blender for Windows developer):*
>
> Windows Smart Screen is throwing a fit, since we are a new publisher it has never seen before.
> There is nothing we can do on our side about smartscreen except wait for it to have enough data to trust us.

**Temporary solution**
(versions that don't trigger Windows Smart Screen)
[Blender from Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/blender/9pp3c07gtvrh)
[Blender from Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/)

There's a whole thread on [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/T71784) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Where'd you download the installer from? Mine's signed correctly.

[image]